# Is there any way to use Composer download packages without docs and testing things?

Tags: php, composer-php

I know Gem can do that, and I really don't need the docs and testing things.

Can Composer do that also? Thanks.

Comment: you could try passing the `--no-dev` flag... but im not sure if that would exclude what you want or not. I've never used it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `--prefer-dist`. And if there is a dist version for your repository it will be downloaded. You also can use `--no-dev` flag to exclude libraries that listed in `require-dev` section of packages. These libraries maybe useful only for development.